# C# statement reachability and definite assignment

Tags: c#, variable-assignment

I am stumped by the reaction from csc to this code:

```
{
  int i;
  if (false)
  {
    i++;                // uninitialized, but allowed by compiler
  }
  if (false && i < 30)  // uninitialized, but allowed by compiler
  {
  }
  if (false && i < 30)  // uninitialized, but allowed by compiler
  {
    i++;                // NOT ALLOWED by compiler??
  }
}
```

In this code I've got three `if`s and one uninitialized local variable i. CSC is smart enough to tolerate my use of i in the first and second cases since it can tell the code where i is being used is unreachable. Yet on the third case, it complains on the increment of i "use of unassigned local variable i". Why is it correctly detecting i is in unreachable code in the first two ifs, but not in the third (which is nothing but a combination of the first two cases?

Comment: This question isn't *really* about definite assignment - it's about reachability.

Comment: Where do you get uninitialised from? int is a value type, so it is initialised to zero.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson i is a local variable, these are not initialized automatically for you! As to where do I get it, it is the compiler that gave me this error!

Comment: Yes they are, all value types are initialised in .net. Read up on the CLR

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I do not know how to relate your comment to this case, the following sequence of statements, in a method, do not compile: int kk;Console.WriteLine(kk); This is not a CLR issue, it is a C# issue

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: It's not a matter for the CLR to decide exclusively. This is a *language* decision, and C# won't let you read a local variable which isn't definitely assigned. Just try it! `int x; Console.WriteLine(x);`

Comment: @Jon, good point. Didn't think far enough round that corner. Decades of good habits means I always initialise my variables, before I use them. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is explained by section 8.7.1 of the C# 5 specification:

> The first embedded statement of an `if` statement is reachable if the `if` statement is reachable and the boolean expression does not have the constant value `false`.

Even though *we* can reason that this condition:

```
false && i < 30
```

is always `false`, it's not a constant expression according to the rules of the language (7.19), so the first embedded statement in the body is reachable.

It's not that everything involving `&&` is non-false. This is fine, for example:

```
if (false && true)
{
    i++;
}
```

... but because the expression `i < 30` isn't constant, your original expression isn't constant. This is the case *even though we know that expression would never be evaluated*.

The language *could* decide that any `&&` expression where the LHS had a constant expression of `false` was also a constant expression with the value `false`, but it doesn't. (It would only be a small amount of added complexity, but the level of benefit is *really* small.)